# Error: Error: the "filename" option is required to use includes and extends with "relative" paths

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, webpack, pug, jestjs

I'm using Vue with webpack template and I'm trying to run tests with Jest. I'm also using Pug to render the templates.

But when I run the tests I get the error:

```
[vue-jest] Error: Error: the "filename" option is required to use includes and extends with "relative" paths
    at undefined line 2


  at error (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/throw-error.js:2:9)
  at module.exports (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/compilers/pug-compiler.js:11:5)
  at getTemplateContent (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/template-compiler.js:11:12)
  at compileTemplate (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/template-compiler.js:23:25)
  at Object.module.exports [as process] (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/process.js:70:29)
```

Running coverage on untested files...Failed to collect coverage from /Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
ERROR:
[vue-jest] Error: Error: the "filename" option is required to use includes and extends with "relative" paths
    at undefined line 2

STACK: Error:
[vue-jest] Error: Error: the "filename" option is required to use includes and extends with "relative" paths
    at undefined line 2

```
at error (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/vue-jest/lib/throw-error.js:2:9)
at module.exports (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/vue-jest/lib/compilers/pug-compiler.js:11:5)
at getTemplateContent (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/vue-jest/lib/template-compiler.js:11:12)
at compileTemplate (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/vue-jest/lib/template-compiler.js:23:25)
at Object.module.exports [as process] (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/vue-jest/lib/process.js:70:29)
at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:247:35)
at exports.default (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/generate_empty_coverage.js:16:105)
at Object.worker (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/reporters/coverage_worker.js:48:84)
at execMethod (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/jest-worker/build/child.js:83:29)
at process.on (/Users/magno.sousa/Documents/playground/vue-test/vuetest/node_modules/jest-worker/build/child.js:40:7)
```

Here is my Vue component

```js
<template lang="pug">
  include HelloWorld.pug
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and my jest config file

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  'vue-jest': {
    pug: {
      filename: 'pug'
    }
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/setup'],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/test/unit/coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.js',
    '!src/router/index.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**'
  ]
}
```

I tried to add the filename option in the jest config but it's not working. Can anyone help out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should specify `baseDir` to be able to use `include\extends` with jest testing and include files in your tempaltes like `include /HelloWorld.pug`.

And in jest config it should be:

```
'vue-jest': {
  pug: {
    baseDir: path.join(__dirname, 'my/folder/with/views');
  }
 },
```

**P.S.** Also your webpack configuration of pug-loader should be changed (I think `root` property of pug-loader options).

Comment: I made the change, but now I get:  `ERROR:
[vue-jest] Error: Error: the "basedir" option is required to use includes and extends with "absolute" paths
    at undefined line 2

STACK: Error:
[vue-jest] Error: Error: the "basedir" option is required to use includes and extends with "absolute" paths
    at undefined line 2`

Comment: what is your `vue-jest` and `jest` versions? I just set up Vue project with pug templates and it works fine even with relative paths in `include`.

Comment: "vue-jest": "^1.0.2" and "jest": "^22.0.4" Can you maybe share your configuration?

Comment: try update your `vue-jest` to 2.6.0 and jest, remove `vue-jest` section from `jest.config.js` and make your `inlcude`(like in your question example) relative, I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `vue-jest` params under global prop in jest config:

```
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "vue-jest": {
      "pug": {
        "basedir": "./"
      }
    }
  },
```